# C++: fread reads different sizes each time

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file, encryption, openssl

here is my code:

```
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>

#define KEY_LENGTH  2048
#define PUB_EXP     3
#define PRINT_KEYS
#define WRITE_TO_FILE

int main(void) {

    size_t pri_len;            // Length of private key
    size_t pub_len;            // Length of public key
    char   *pri_key;           // Private key
    char   *pub_key;           // Public key
    char   *msg = (char *)malloc(256);  // Message to encrypt
    char   *encrypt = NULL;    // Encrypted message
    char   *decrypt = NULL;    // Decrypted message
    char   *err = NULL;               // Buffer for any error messages
    size_t red;

    RSA *keypair = RSA_generate_key(KEY_LENGTH, 3, NULL, NULL);
    FILE *out;
    FILE *in;

    char *direct = (char*)malloc(256);


    if (fopen_s(&in, "test.txt", "r") != 0)
    {
        printf("in Error is %d.\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }
    if (fopen_s(&out, "etest.txt", "w") != 0)
    {
        printf("out Error is %d.\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    encrypt = (char *)malloc(RSA_size(keypair));

    setvbuf(out, encrypt, _IOFBF, RSA_size(keypair));

    for (;;)
    {
        red = fread(msg, 1, RSA_size(keypair) - 42, in);
        std::cout << "encrypt read -> " << red << std::endl;
        if (red == 0) break;
        if (((red = RSA_public_encrypt(RSA_size(keypair) - 42, (unsigned char*)msg, (unsigned char*)encrypt,
            keypair, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING))) == -1) {
            ERR_load_crypto_strings();
            ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err);
            fprintf(stderr, "Error encrypting message: %d\n", err);
        }
        std::cout << "encrypted size -> " << red << std::endl;
        if (fwrite(encrypt, 1, red, out) == 1)
        {
            printf("fwrite Error is %d (%d).\n", errno);
        }

    }

    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);

    if (fopen_s(&in, "etest.txt", "r") != 0)
    {
        printf("in Error is %d (%s).\n", errno);
    }
    if (fopen_s(&out, "dtest.txt", "w") != 0)
    {
        printf("out Error is %d (%s).\n", errno);
    }


    decrypt = (char *)malloc(RSA_size(keypair) - 42);

    for (;;)
    {
        red = fread(msg, 1, RSA_size(keypair), in);

        std::cout << "red decrypt -> " << red << std::endl;

        if (red < RSA_size(keypair)) break;
        if ((red = RSA_private_decrypt(red, (unsigned char*)msg, (unsigned char*)decrypt,
            keypair, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING)) == -1) {

            ERR_load_crypto_strings();
            ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err);
            fprintf(stderr, "Error decrypting message: %d\n", err);
        }

        fwrite(decrypt, 1, red, out);
        std::cout << decrypt << std::endl;



    }
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    RSA_free(keypair);
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is simple, I have a word `GIO` in `test.txt`, I open it and encrypt using `RSA` keys which I generate, then I write the encrypted data into  `etest.txt`, then I open it and try to decrypt and write decrypted data into `dtest.txt`. This is a simple example for educational purposes.

The problem that I'm having is that when I encrypt the data `RSA_public_encrypt` returns `256` which is great, I write `256` bytes into `etest.txt`. But when I try to open the same file for decryption and read from it the log message `std::cout << "red decrypt -> " << red << std::endl;` returns different amount. For example sometimes it's `24`, `47`, `50` sometimes it's even `256`. In the case of `256` I open the `dtest.txt` and I see the data

`GIOÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ`

which is not what I encrypted. So my question is why I read different amount of data from `etest.txt` everytime? and why do I get wrong decrypted data in case I read `256` bytes?

Comment: You're actually programming in C++ and not C.

Comment: I also suggest you switch the sizes of your `fread` and `fwrite` around. Instead of reading e.g. `RSA_size(keypair)` amount of bytes, you write one "object" of `1, RSA_size(keypair)` bytes (i.e. do `fread(msg, RSA_size(keypair), 1, in)`).

Comment: As for your problem, are you sure the encrypted data is *text* data and not binary? You should always use the `"b"` flag for binary data (i.e. `fopen_s(&out, "etest.txt", "wb")`). That could make a big difference in the data you write and read. Especially since for text-file the "end-of-file" character on Windows (`Ctrl-Z`, decimal value `26`)  is an end-of-file marker when reading the file as text.

Comment: when I switch sizes of `fread` and `write` as you suggested but now `fread` for decryption returns 0

Comment: I also changed `fopen` as you said but I get the output I said